# LINQ expression to get the whole content of right table

Tags: entity-framework, linq

In my database, I have these two tables with a relationship :

[image]

I would like to get the whole content of the "assignee_kanban" column in "assigneekanban" table (which for now contains six names).

Here is the expression I use (in my "Kanban" controller using entity framework) :

```
public List<Kanban> LoadCard() {
  return _context.Kanbans.Include(c => c.IdAssigneeKanbanNavigation).ToList();}
```

When I try to get the result in my razor page with :

```
@foreach (var name in Kanbans)
 {
    <tr> 
       <td>@name.IdAssigneeKanbanNavigation.AssigneeKanban1</td>                                       
    </tr>
 }
```

unfortunatly, the result I get contains only three names : the three names corresponding to the three "id_assignee_kanban" that exist in the "kanban" table.

**How can I get all the names contained in the "assignee_kanban" column ?**
*(I succeed to get the values using assigneekanban controller but for some reason, I want to use kanban controller with the navigation statement)*

(project webassembly blazor using .net 6 aspnet hosted)

Thank you for your help.

Here is the content of the "kanban" table (I removed some no important columns for this problem) :
[image]

Here is the content of the "assigneekanban" table :
[image]

Here is the output :
[image]

As we can see, the name "Robert" corresponding to the id n°5 doesn't appaer in the result and the other names appear as many time they exist in the kanban table (of course, I can add a distinct close to avoid duplicate names but it doesn't bring the missing name !).

Comment: Could you provide an example of the contents of `kanban`, the contents of `assigneekanban`, the output you get with your current code and the output you want to achieve?

Comment: Hi Astrid, thank you for your interest to my problem. I updated my post with what you excepcted.

Comment: Thank you for updating with an example, Phil. When I first read _for some reason, I want to use kanban controller with the navigation statement_, I figured _the reason_ would be that you needed something from the `kanban` table as well, but now it looks like you really only want the content of the `assigneekanban` -- is that correct? (I do not think I can be of help, unfortunately.)

Comment: Thank you Astrid for your new comment. The way you understood my question is the right one. It seems my need corresponds to a right join query. After hours digging on the web, I still don't have a response to my problem using Linq method ! Thank you for your help anyway.

Comment: Hello Wertzui,
thank you for your answer. Unfortunatelly, I can't write these three Tasks because I use a third-party component which can be configured to reach only one.
I finally found another way to use this component and were able to get my "AssigneeKanban1" from the single "Assigneekanban" Task.
Sincerly.

Comment: You may want to comment directly on Wertzui's post, so that they are notified about it :)

Answer (score 1):

You need a second query to get all entries from the `assigneekanban` table. Your current implementation will only get those values from the `assigneekanban` that have a foreign key entry in the `kanban table` (Basically doing an `INNER JOIN`).

```
public async Task<List<Kanban>> LoadCardAsync() 
{
    return _context.Kanbans.ToList();
}

public async Task<List<AssigneeKanban>> LoadAssigneesAsync() 
{
    return _context.AssigneeKanbans.ToList();
}

public async Task LoadEverythingAsync()
{
    Kanbans = await LoadCardAsync();
    Assignees = await LoadAssigneesAsync();
}
```

Then in your Razor Page

```
@foreach (var assignee in Assignees)
{
    <tr> 
        <td>@assignee.AssigneeKanban1</td>                                       
    </tr>
}
```